Error al pasar una variable con una cadena a una funcion con onclick / el texo en string se separa y genera erro
Hola estoy intentando pasar varias variables a una función que se llama traer_producto , pero cuando paso una variable por ejemplo que es "ZONA 3 ", al revisarlo se ve que esta se separa y genera un error en la función.
CODIGO PHP
                $table .= '<tr tabindex="'.$tab.'" class="fila_elegir" id="fila_elegir'.($n-1).'" 
                onclick=traer_producto("'.$row['id_producto'].'","'.$row['lote'].'","'.$row['fechavencimiento'].'","'.$row['stock'].'","'.$row['id_lote'].'","'.$row['id_productop'].'","'.$row['sin_lotes'].'","'.$row['sucursal_lote'].'","'.$row['sucursal_producto'].'","'.$row['IDR'].'","'.($n-1).'","'.$row['unidad'].'","'.$row['zona'].'","'.$row['rack'].'","'.$row['fila'].'","'.$row['columna'].'")
                onkeypress=traer_producto("'.$row['id_producto'].'","'.$row['lote'].'","'.$row['fechavencimiento'].'","'.$row['stock'].'","'.$row['id_lote'].'","'.$row['id_productop'].'","'.$row['sin_lotes'].'","'.$row['sucursal_lote'].'","'.$row['sucursal_producto'].'","'.$row['IDR'].'","'.($n-1).'","'.$row['unidad'].'","'.$row['zona'].'","'.$row['rack'].'","'.$row['fila'].'","'.$row['columna'].'")>';
                    $table .= '<td>'.$n++.'</td>';
                    $table .= '<td id="codprod_ori2_'.($n-1).'" >'.$row['id_producto'].'</td>';
                    $table .= '<td>'.$row['descripcion'].'</td>';
                    $table .= '<td id="lote_ori2_'.($n-1).'" >'.$row['lote'].'</td>';
                    $table .= '<td id="fecing_ori2_'.($n-1).'" >'.$row['fechaingreso'].'</td>';
                    $table .= '<td id="fecven_ori2_'.($n-1).'" >'.$row['fechavencimiento'].'</td>';
                    $table .= '<td id="stock_ori2_'.($n-1).'" >'.$row['stock'].'</td>';
                    $table .= '<td id="zona_ori2_'.($n-1).'" >'.$row['zona'].'</td>';
                    $table .= '<td id="rack_ori2_'.($n-1).'" >'.$row['rack'].'</td>';
                    $table .= '<td id="columna_ori2_'.($n-1).'" >'.$row['columna'].'</td>';
                    $table .= '<td id="fila_ori2_'.($n-1).'" >'.$row['fila'].'</td>';
                    $table .= '<td>'.$row['unidad'].'</td>';
                    $table .= '<td>'.$row['nombre_sucursal'].'</td>';
                    $table .= '<td><input type="radio" id="reubicar_stock_dest_'.($n-1).'" name="check_dest" /></td>';
                $table .= '</tr>';

RESULTADO

ERROR AL PASAR LOS DATOS

Muchas gracias de antemano por su ayuda

uff pobre de el que tenga hacer mantenimiento a ese código. ¿La tabla es editable?

No se yo si deberias agregar comillas dobles en el onclick y el onkeypress que encierren toda la función que pretendes llamar, pues carecen de ellas e intuyo que parte del problema puede venir de alli.  Por otra parte, en lugar de usar comillas dobles en los parámetros de las funciones de dichos atributos, quizás deberias usar comillas simples escapándolas con la barra invertida.

Estas usando PHP parea "generar" código HTML, no hagas eso. Solo imprime lo necesario con PHP y el resto que sea como debe ser, HTML

Refactorizando tu problema, yo lo haria así:
$correlacion = [
    $n => null,
    "id_producto" => "codprod_ori2_",
    "descripcion" => null,
    "lote" => "lote_ori2_",
    "fechaingreso" => "fecing_ori2_",
    "fechavencimiento" => "fecven_ori2_",
    "stock" => "stock_ori2_",
    "zona" => "zona_ori2_",
    "rack" => "rack_ori2_",
    "columna" => "columna_ori2_",
    "fila" => "fila_ori2_",
    "unidad" => null,
    "nombre_sucursal" => null
];
$columnas = '';
foreach ($correlacion as $var => $id) {
    if (is_null($id)) {
        $columnas .= '<td>'.$row[$var].'</td>';
    } else {
        $columnas .= '<td id="'.$id.$n.'"> '.$row[$var].'</td>';
    }
}

$table .= '
<tr tabindex="'.$tab.'" class="fila_elegir" id="fila_elegir'.$n.'" 
    onclick="traer_producto(\''.$row['id_producto'].'\')"
    onkeypress="traer_producto(\''.$row['id_producto'].'\')"
>
    '.$columnas.'
    <td><input type="radio" id="reubicar_stock_dest_'.$n.'" name="check_dest" /></td>
</tr>';                
$n++;

Como ves los cambios no son pocos, y no voy a explicarlos uno a uno, espero que tu misma los veas, pero si que quiero aclararte estos:
    onclick="traer_producto(\''.$row['id_producto'].'\')"
    onkeypress="traer_producto(\''.$row['id_producto'].'\')"

donde he encerrado entre comillas simples el parámetro, escapándolas con la barra inclinada, y agregando comillas dobles al principio y al final del atributo, para evitar que nada las ponga por mi (que creo que es el problema que tu tienes realmente).
He omitido todo el resto de parámetros de la función traer_producto porque entiendo que esa misma función, basándose en el id_producto, debe ser capaz de buscar esos datos allí donde los tengas, en lugar de pasarlos como parámetros complicando tanto el código y su mantenimiento.
En todo caso, si no sabes como hacerlo, pregúntalo en una nueva pregunta para que te ayudemos a ello.

Muchas gracias!! pude solucionarlo
